# Shutting down Executorservice error in Google cloud platform

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, google-cloud-platform

I have an Spring boot application where I upload multiple files and after submitting, it will convert all files to `byte[]` and attach these files to  an email.
It is working fine in local. When I upload files, which are more than 5MB, but it is not working fine after uploading it to Google Cloud Platform.

Below is the error that I am getting.

```
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]  {"severity": "WARNING", "message": "App is listening on port 8080. We recommend your app listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable to take advantage of an NGINX layer on port 8080."}\njava.lang.NullPointerException
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at taxtown.taxfile.controller.TaxRestController.getFormData(TaxRestController.java:238)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-04-17 02:07:13 default[20200416t214835]  --------------Excepiton is----------null
2020-04-17 02:07:21 default[20200416t214835]  2020-04-17 02:07:21.593  INFO 10 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-17 02:07:21 default[20200416t214835]  2020-04-17 02:07:21.594  INFO 11 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-17 02:07:21 default[20200416t214835]  2020-04-17 02:07:21.594  INFO 11 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-17 02:07:21 default[20200416t214835]  2020-04-17 02:07:21.641  INFO 10 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-17 02:07:22 default[20200416t214835]  {"severity": "WARNING", "message": "App is listening on port 8080. We recommend your app listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable to take advantage of an NGINX layer on port 8080."}\n
2020-04-17 02:07:22 default[20200416t214835]  {"severity": "WARNING", "message": "App is listening on port 8080. We recommend your app listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable to take advantage of an NGINX layer on port 8080."}\n
2020-04-17 02:07:22 default[20200416t214835]  {"severity": "WARNING", "message": "App is listening on port 8080. We recommend your app listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable to take advantage of an NGINX layer on port 8080."}\n
2020-04-17 02:07:22 default[20200416t214835]  {"severity": "WARNING", "message": "App is listening on port 8080. We recommend your app listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable to take advantage of an NGINX layer on port 8080."}\n
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From your description looks like the Maven/Gradle dependencies for Spring web are correctly set and the GCE firewall rules are OK (as the app is implied to be serving content). GCE instances don't do any changes on apps itself (they're just VPSs) so I'm guessing the issue is in your Java env. Just to rule out GCE, can you give more details on that? This output only points to an executor error that is related to the Java environment itself, not GCP.

Comment: Thank you @yyyyahir for the comment. I have figured it out after doing lot of research. From long time, i was only seeing logs of gcloud SDK. But from the logs of GCP account, i came to know that it happened because of my soft memory limit exceeded.

Comment: Good to know. Maybe worth to post an answer for future reference? Up to you. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I will post it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to memory error. It was not shown in the gcloud logs console. But i have seen that in GCP logs.

Below is the error.

```
Exceeded soft memory limit of 256 MB with 322 MB after servicing 3 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml
```